# Is there a way to set off timer evnets in blackberry?

Tags: events, blackberry, timer

I'm making a simple matching game and would like a count down timer.  Is there a way to set off an event every dt? I found some code using threads, but seems a lot more complicated for what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
TimerTask countdown = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        synchronized(UiApplication.getEventLock()) {
            //do the stuff to the UI, ie change the counter
        }
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(countdown, 0, dt);
```

I didn't test this, so I may have a typo in there, but this is the basic idea. Take a look at the [TimerTask](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/TimerTask.html) and [Timer](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/util/Timer.html) documentation for more info.

Comment: Hi thank you,this gave me enough information to look it up on google.